Thermal Printer algorithm to encode images to printable hex stream
I am trying to print on my thermal printer using the web Bluetooth API. I can send hex data to the printer and it prints but I need an algorithm to have the correct hex values which I can then send to the printer. I sniffed the data sent to the printer when I printed something using the designated software. The print command always starts with:
1b 00 20 5a fc a5 86 97 ff ff 00 00 00 00 09 00 00 01 00 04 00 02 03 93 25 00 00 1b 4e 0d 05 1b 4e 04 06 1f 11 0a 1d 76 30 00 28 00 f0 00 00
The following hex values (9600) are (in decimal) 0-255. 0 = nothing; printed 1-255 something printed? That's where my problem is. It's not simply more heat output, it's something else because the printed dots don't become larger they act differently for example they become two dots for some values, thinner and thicker. I don't see how that works. Is there some algorithm to encode images to correct the thermal printer hex stream? I would like to understand how that works, thanks in advance!
also: I figured out my labels are 40 hex values wide and 240 high. I can print lines (easy calculations) and so on but nothing more complex :(

https://reference.epson-biz.com/modules/ref_escpos/index.php?content_id=2
